# InterFrame Homography Error

Tags: opencv, homography, projection-matrix

I am using interframe homography to compute scene homography and visuzalize graphics into a video captured by pure rotating and zooming camera. 
Final scene homography(Hscene) is computed as:
Hscene = Hinterframe * Hscene;
by using OpenCV.
I know that there cumulative error can occur caused by partial interframe homography errors.
But I have some video sequences, where ocurrs another error. This error manifests also as drift of visualized graphics. The drift is more visible when graphics is projected to the image border.
The first idea was lens distortion, but the video does not contain any distortion. When I compute direct homography from initial to target frame, projection is also without drift.

Do you have idea, what causes this drift and how to eliminate it?

[EDITED 5.9.2012]
The cause is lens distortion. It is possible to estimate it from interframe feature point correspondences?

Comment: It's a good chance that you see a genuine drift in camera position. If you do not estimate and eliminate it, all your frames will be reprojected to a point of view that's more and more out of the current frame. Image you move yur camera moves to left, but your subject stays in front of you. You will loose it.

Comment: Camera is rigid in position. Such drift should be visible also when find homography between starting and final image directly.

Comment: So you have an error when you use several interframe homographys but not when you calculate between the first and last frame?  Why is that different than the error "caused by partial interframe homography errors?"  An error in your homography will translate into an error in your visualized graphics.

Comment: So you have an error when you use several interframe homographys but not when you calculate between the first and last frame? Exactly

Comment: Why is that different than the error "caused by partial interframe homography errors?" I did not see soo great drift on relatively small frame count for now. Other video sekvences has small drift or flickering which is not soo strong as here. Also RMS Error is relativelly small.